# Airflow folder structure on how to incorporate container with custom code to avoid bloat

Tags: python, docker, airflow

Airflow beginner here.  I have a question on how to install a custom utility package in a docker container that will be used in docker compose for airflow.  The reason why I want to do this is because this package has a lot of reusable code and I don't want to constantly copy the code into new projects directories.

The custom utility package that I would use would only be needed for the Webserver container.

Since I am aiming not to copy the utility code into my docker compose directory, would I need to install it in a separate container then reference (through extending?) that container somewhere in my airflow directory?  I hope I'm not overcomplicating.

My current airflow setup is as follows:

```
Airflow_ETL
--/airflow
--/scripts
   -/data
   -/resource
   -pull_data.py
--docker-compose.yml
--Dockerfile
--env.list
--requirements.txt
```

My docker file looks likes this:

```
FROM puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9

COPY airflow/airflow.cfg ${AIRFLOW_HOME}/airflow.cfg

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install SQLAlchemy==1.3.15

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
```

Docker Compose uses this Docker File to build the rest of the containers.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
    redis:
        image: redis:5.0.5

    flower:
        image: flower:latest
        build:
          context: .
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - redis
        environment:
            - EXECUTOR=Celery
        ports:
            - "5555:5555"
        command: flower

    webserver:
        image: webserver:latest
        build:
          context: .
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - postgres
            - redis
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=n
            - FERNET_KEY=46BKJoQYlPPOexq0OhDZnIlNepKFf87WFwLbfzqDDho=
            - EXECUTOR=Celery
            - PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/airflow
        env_file:
          - env.list
        volumes:
            - ./airflow/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            - ./scripts:/usr/local/airflow/scripts
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        command: webserver
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 30s
            retries: 3

    scheduler:
        image: scheduler:latest
        build:
          context: .
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - webserver
        volumes:
            - ./airflow/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            - ./scripts:/usr/local/airflow/scripts
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=n
            - FERNET_KEY=46BKJoQYlPPOexq0OhDZnIlNepKFf87WFwLbfzqDDho=
            - EXECUTOR=Celery
            - PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/airflow
        command: scheduler
        env_file:
          - env.list

    worker1:
        image: worker1:latest
        build:
          context: .
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - scheduler
        volumes:
            - ./airflow/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            - ./scripts:/usr/local/airflow/scripts
        environment:
            - FERNET_KEY=46BKJoQYlPPOexq0OhDZnIlNepKFf87WFwLbfzqDDho=
            - EXECUTOR=Celery
            - PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/airflow
        command: worker
        env_file:
          - env.list

    worker2:
        image: worker2:latest
        build:
          context: .
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - scheduler
        volumes:
            - ./airflow/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            - ./scripts:/usr/local/airflow/scripts
        environment:
            - FERNET_KEY=46BKJoQYlPPOexq0OhDZnIlNepKFf87WFwLbfzqDDho=
            - EXECUTOR=Celery
            - PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/airflow
        command: worker
        env_file:
          - env.list
```

Thank you for your time.